# If $\Gamma$ is differentiable on $(0,\infty)$, then it is differentiable on whole $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0,-1,-2,\dots\}$.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, gamma-function

It is well-known that the Gamma function $\Gamma$ satisfies
$$\Gamma(x+1)=x\Gamma(x)\tag{1}$$
for all $x\in \mathbb{R}\setminus \{0,-1,-2,\dots\}$. I have shown that $\log\Gamma$ is differentiable on $(0,\infty)$. Since $\Gamma = \exp(\log \Gamma)$, we have that $\Gamma$ is differentiable on $(0,\infty)$. Now, the question is:

**Question**: How to conclude from $(1)$ that $\Gamma$ is differentiable on whole $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0,-1,-2,\dots\}$?

It may seem too obvious, but how would you explain it mathematically?

Comment: What's $\Gamma^\prime(x+1)$?

Comment: @J.G. It is $\Gamma'(x+1)=x\Gamma'(x)+\Gamma(x)$, which is valid only for $x>0$ (due to differentiability of $\Gamma$ on $(0,\infty)$). From this, we get $$\Gamma'(x)=\frac{\Gamma'(x+1)-\Gamma(x)}{x},$$ still for $x>0$. Should I redefine it for $x>-1$, $x\neq 0$? I initially thought about it before posting my question, but it seemed a tedious approach

Comment: If $x_0 \le 0$, then find some $n \in \Bbb{N}$ such that $x_0 + n > 0$. You can express $$\Gamma(x) = \frac{\Gamma(x + n)}{x(x + 1)\ldots(x + n - 1)},$$which is the quotient of functions differentiable at $x_0$, and provided $x_0 \notin \Bbb{Z}$, the denominator is non-zero. Quotient rule applies.

Comment: @TheoBendit Wow, I think I got it. Could you please confirm if my understanding is correct: Let $x\in (-\infty,0]$ except at $0,-1,-2,\dots$, and choose $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $x\in (-n,-n+1)$. We know that $$\Gamma(x)=\Gamma(x+n)\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}(x+i)^{-1},$$ Since $x+n>0$, $\Gamma(x+n)$ is differentiable for $x\in (-n,-n+1)$, and the denominator is clearly differentiable on $(-n,-n+1)$ as well. Hence, looking at the left-hand side, $\Gamma$ is differentiable on $(-n,-n+1)$. Since $n$ is arbitrary,it follows that $\Gamma$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0,-1,-2,\dots\}$.

Comment: @Mr.MathDoctor Your understanding is good! I'd just like to point out, when you mention "the denominator", you seem to be referring to $\prod_{i=0}^{n-1} (x + i)$, which is differentiable everywhere. To ensure differentiability of the quotient, it is important that it also be non-zero at the point in question, which is why I made sure to highlight it in my comment above. I believe you already understand this, but it's worth clarifying. Now that you're clear about all this, I would advise putting your comment as an answer to your own question.